# How to issue shell commands to slave machines from master and wait until all are finished?

Tags: shell, sh, distributed

I have 4 shell commands I need to run and they do not depend on each other.

I have 4 slave machines.  So, I want to run one of the 4 commands on each of the 4 machines, and then I want to wait until all 4 of them are finished.

How do I distribute this processing?  This is what I tried:

`$1` is a list of ip addresses to the slave machines.

```
for host in $(cat $1)
do
    echo $host
    # ssh into each machine and launch command
    ssh username@$host <command>;
done
```

But this seems as if it is waiting for the command to finish before moving on to the next `host` and launching the next command.

How do I accomplish this distributed processing that doesn't depend on each other?

Answer (score 2):

I would use **GNU Parallel** like this - running `hostname` in parallel on each of 4 servers:

```
parallel -j 4 --nonall -S 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2,192.168.0.3,192.168.0.4 hostname
```

If you need to pass parameters, use `--onall` and put arguments after `:::`

```
parallel -j 4 --onall -S 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2,192.168.0.3,192.168.0.4 echo ::: hello
```

Add `--tag` if you want the output lines tagged by the hostname/IP.

Add `-k` if you want to keep the output in order.

Add `:` to the server list to run on local host too.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't concerned about how many commands run concurrently, just put each one in the background with `&`, then wait on them as a group.

```
while IFS= read -r host; do
    ssh username@$host <command> &
done < "$1"
wait
```

Note the use of a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop; see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 0):

The ssh part of your script needs to be like:

```
$ ssh -f user@host "sh -c 'sleep 30 ; nohup ls > foo 2>&1 &'"
```

This one sleeps for 30 secs and writes the output of `ls` to file `foo`. 30 secs is enough for you to go and see it yourself. Just build your loop around that.

Comment: when you say "go and see it yourself" you don't mean check manually right?

Comment: That's what I meant with that `sleep 30`. Manual validation that it works.

Comment: I need this to be automated

Comment: No doubt. Therefore: _Just build your loop around that [ssh command]_.

Comment: You also need a `wait` after the loop.